# Active Model Serializer send parent of has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

In my Comments controller, I serialize the comments. When I put a `belongs_to :post_id` in my serializer, every comment has a post with it, but since all of these comments come from the same post, it is redundant. I know I can use the post serializer with a has_many comments, but since I'm n the comments controller that doesn't seem idiomatic. How would I achieve this?

Hoping for: `{ comments: { ... }, post: { ... } }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent redundant inclusion of associations, set [`embed`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/active_model_serializers/0.8.3/ActiveModel/Serializer.embed):

```
embed :objects               # Embed associations as full objects
embed :ids                   # Embed only the association ids
embed :ids, :include => true # Embed the association ids and include objects in the root
```

So

```
class Comments < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true
end
```

will include the post only once at the top level:

```
{
  comments: [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "Foo",
      post_id: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "Bar",
      post_id: 1
    }
  ],
  posts: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Lorem ipsum"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want to include or leave out associations completely depending on the situation, [this wonderful StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969622/100342) has a nifty solution for that by (ab)using eager loading:

```
class Comments < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :text, :poster_id

  belongs_to :poster

  def include_poster?
    object.association(:poster).loaded?
  end

  def include_poster_id?
    !include_poster?
  end
end
```

Now by clearing the `post` association you can prevent it from being included at all:

```
@comments = @post.comments
@comments.post.reset

respond_with @comments
```

In reverse, explicitly eager loading an association will include it:

```
@comments = Comment.includes(:poster).order(id: :asc).limit(10)
respond_with @comments
```

Comment: How would this apply if I get comments like such `@comments = @post.comments`? I already have the post. It is a matter of getting it included. A quick hack is to just include it in the meta, but I'm not too keen on that.

Comment: @David I think I see what you mean, except for the meta part?

Comment: @David `embed include: true` should do the trick. Regarding `@comments = @post.comments`, you can unload an association by calling `.reset` on it. `@comments = @post.comments ; @comments.post.reset` will leave the `post` unhydrated.

Comment: This is a very _pro_ topic, and for the same reason I didn't get it.. It seems. :-(

Comment: @janfoeh Thanks for your willingness. First let me know if it is Rails out of the box functionality ?

Comment: Ohkay! This is a very good learning for me.. Thanks.. Hope I'll learn more from you. I never saw this stuff in my 7 months career. :)

Comment: friend +1, for this extensive explanation.